# Javascript Date() return undefined

Tags: javascript, date, react-native

I am using Javasript's Date() method to extract current date simply. It was working fine with my react native project but stopped suddenly.

```js
let TodayDate = new Date();
console.log(TodayDate);
```

This prints me `undefined`. I tried testing with browser's console and it works fine but does not give any output in my files.

My snippet I am trying:

```js
getDateToday = () => {
  let dateToday = new Date();
  console.log(dateToday);
};

function componentDidMount() {
  this.getDateToday();
}

componentDidMount();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Kindly help me resolve the issue.

Comment: It's simple. that is what bothering me. I tried with online editors and everytime it works. I have added snippet too, just to confirm. But it print 'undefined' only from my files.

Comment: If i alert the output, it's just [object object].

Comment: @PaulRooney I can create an online example but it will work over there.

Comment: Maybe you override `Date` somewhere?

Comment: could it be that you're trying to use the method something like `console.log(this.getDateToday());` and this gives you `undefined`?

Comment: @Thomas No. I am simply loggin the variable

Comment: `If i alert the output, it's just [object object].` which is exactly what I'd expect. I don't understand why `alert()` would say that it is an `Object` but `console.log()` would say `undefined`. This somehow doesn't add up.

Comment: Do you declare a variable `Date` anywhere in that file?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
new Date()
```

To:

```
new Date().toLocaleString();
```

Your code may look like:

```
    getDateToday = () => {
                let dateToday = new Date().toLocaleString();

                console.log(dateToday)
            }

    componentDidMount(){
         this.getDateToday();
    }
```